# htaccess RewriteRule removing extension not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please help me address my problem, the RewriteRuel 1, 2 and 3 is working. The 4th RewriteRule is not working it sends back 404 error.

```
 1. RewriteRule pahina-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)$ pahina.php?page_id=$1&page_title=$2&user_name=$3 [L]
 2. RewriteRule pahina-(.*)-(.*)$ pahina.php?page_id=$1&page_title=$2 [L]
 3. RewriteRule pahina-(.*)$ pahina.php?user_name=$1 [L]
 4. RewriteRule ^pahina$ pahina.php [L]
```

The 4th RewriteRule is not working, what I want is to change pahina.php to pahina only without extension... Please help me...

Thanks and best regards...

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code used to remove the .php extension

```
# Remove .php-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php
```

Add this in .htaccess file. This will remove all .php extension.
Specify your file name there

Comment: Have tried your code @Santosh it works on my local machine, but when I uploaded it to my website still the same error... 

Thanks friend...

Comment: Have you tried restarting server...and also check you are editing correct file. If it worked then accept the answer so others can use it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your patterns are using anchors to avoid matching unwanted text:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^pahina-([^_]*)-([^_]*)-(.*)$ pahina.php?page_id=$1&page_title=$2&user_name=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^pahina-([^_]*)-(.*)$ pahina.php?page_id=$1&page_title=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^pahina-(.+)$ pahina.php?user_name=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^pahina$ pahina.php [L,QSA]
```